# Перенос и развертывание приложения с бд. express.js + mySql or mongodb.

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

Вопрос собственно тривиальный, однако как оказалось ответ для меня не очевиден.

В процессе поиска работы получил тестовое задание написать простое приложение с базой данных. Возможно ли готовый проект, с бд, как-то залить в репозиторий, что б скачав проект (и запустив сервер) всё работало из коробки, или всё-таки так сделать нельзя, и базу данных всё равно придётся устанавливать тому, кто скачает мой проект.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb - вполне портативная программа. Её достаточно скачать и запустить бинарник с именем "mongod" как [дочерний процесс](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html). Однако у такого решения есть недостаток - оно будет платформозависимым. Если вы хотите, чтоб ваше приложение было кроссплатформенным, придётся хранить копии БД для Windows, Linux, Mac, Solaris.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Короткий ответ, и да и нет. Если использовать ORM то большинство из них умеют делать миграции например http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/docs/migrations/.

Но, как правило миграции надо запускать отдельным скриптом из командной строки.

Можно это дело обернуть и запускать из самого приложения, но тогда надо будет при запуске проверить есть ли база запустить скрипты миграции.

С MongoDB попроще. Из за особенностей ее работы вы используя ODM http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html посути просто создадите классы, а база будет создаваться автоматом.